# in JavaScript toString method doesn't directly run an empty object, instead runs on a variable which is assigned to an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, tostring

I tried this today on my browser console and saw something weird. Please help. Can someone help me understand why It happens ?

Try 1:

```
{}.toString(); // It shows an error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

Try 2:

```
const a = {};
a.toString(); // It returns '[object Object]'
```

Comment: surround with `()`...`({}).toString()`

Comment: Thanks! Why It behaves like this, can you please explain ?

Comment: TLDR; When a statement starts with `{` it's treated as the start of a block, not an object literal.